# creating grid like forms in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I want to create a form similar to drupal's permissions form (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJunz.jpg) using zend framework. any tips to create this using zend Decorators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good explanation from the creator of Zend_Form , he also discusses how to use td,tr html tags to create grid
http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450

Comment: @Jason: Hmmm, I'm getting an invalid link. Confirm?